# Реализовать метод, принимающий (List<String[]> rows, int columnIndex) и сортирующий массивы строк(записи таблицы) по колонке

Tags: java, массивы, строки, сортировка, list

Есть интерфейс , в котором объявлен метод

```
void sort(List<String[]> rows, int columnIndex);
```

Нужно реализовать этот интерфейс в своем классе

```
public class Task1Impl implements IStringRowsListSorter, Comparator<String[]>{

    //реализация должна работать, как singleton. даже при использовании из нескольких потоков.
    public static final IStringRowsListSorter INSTANCE = new Task1Impl();

    @Override
    public void sort(final List<String[]> rows, final int columnIndex) {
//моя реализация


    }
```

Метод принимает в качестве параметров:

rows - таблицу. (List - это , как я понял, список массивов типа String! Я так понял, сама таблица ,например результат запроса)

columnIndex - номер поля в этой таблицы ( индекс колонки), по которой нужно провести сортировку. В нашей структуре это String, получается.

Я так понимаю, что сортировку сделать нужно Используя Comparator.
то есть в классе должен быть переопределен:

```
    @Override     
public int compare(String[] o1, String[] o2) {}
```

МЫ по сути должны отсортировать записи в таблицах, что и передаем Comparator'у, но как ему объяснить что нужно, сортировать по строкам, ведь в Comparator мы не можем передать ещё и columnIndex -

```
      @Override     
            public int compare(String[] o1, String[] o2, int columnIndex) { 
     o1[columnIndex] < o2 [columnIndex]

}
```

Для работы с этим интерфейсом создал тестовый класс, такжу прошу просмотреть правильно ли сделал структуру для работы с массивом и её вывод через for each

```
public class TestIStringRowsListSorter {
   List<String[]> rows = new ArrayList<String[]>();
   public List<String[]> getStruct(){
       return rows;
   }
   public void init(){

    String[] query1 = new String[3]; //   массив строк - строка таблицы
    query1[0] = "Contact"; // 1а строка - 1а запись (1о поле)
    query1[1] = "1"; // 1а строка - 1а запись (1о поле)
    query1[2] = "Peter"; // 1а строка - 1а запись (1о поле)


    String[] query2 = new String[3];
    query2[0] = "Contact";
    query2[1] = "2";
    query2[2] = "Helga";

       rows.add(query1); // добавляем в тестовый Список из массивов строк 1 массив строк
       rows.add(query2); // добавляем в тестовый Список из массивов строк 1 массив строк


   }

   public void showInitStruct(){

            //разобраться как реализован НОВЫй с джава 1.5 способ перебора
       for (String[] tmp: rows){ //для каждого массива строк в списке
           System.out.println("String[] array number " + rows.indexOf(tmp));
           for (String column : tmp) // для каждой строки в массиве строк
           {
               System.out.println(column);
           }
       }

   }

   public String  goTest() {

       return "Sucefull";
   }
}
```

Логика-класс:

```
TestIStringRowsListSorter t = new TestIStringRowsListSorter();
        t.init();
        t.showInitStruct();
```

результат выполнения логики:

```
String[] array number 0
Contact
1
Peter
String[] array number 1
Contact
2
Helga
```

Последние 2 класса создал для упрощения работы. Вопрос, собственно в том, как сделать сортировку используя средства Java - реализовать Comparator, и отсортировать через стандартные методы коллекции, и  если да, то как это сделать?

Answer (score 3):

Внутри вашего `sort` создаёте анонимный компаратор `String[]`, в котором внутри будет виден ваш параметр `columnIndex` (рекомендую ознакомится с информацией об области видимости в inner классах):

```
public void sort(final List<String[]> rows, final int columnIndex) {
        Collections.sort(rows, new Comparator<String[]>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String[] o1, String[] o2) {
                return o1[columnIndex].compareTo(o2[columnIndex]);  
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: И почему я раньше не подумал об анонимных классах!
Скажите, правильно я понял, что метод compareTo в 
`'o1[columnIndex].compareTo(o2[columnIndex]); ` это метод String, т.е. String реализует интерфейс Comparable, и для вычисления результата сравнения массивов строк мы используем результуат вычисления строк по индексу?

Comment: @Mr.Ki.D., да, всё верно.