# Сортировка массивов строк по подстрокам

Tags: java

```
public interface IStringRowsListSorter {

    /**
     * Сортирует переданный список записей (каждая запись - набор колонок) таблицы по указанной колонке по следующим правилам:
     * <ul>
     *  <li>в колонке могут быть null и пустые значения - строки с null-значениями должны быть первыми, затем строки с пустым значением, затем все остальные,</li>
     *  <li>строка бьется на подстроки следующим образом: выделяем непрерывные максимальные фрагменты строки, состоящие только из цифр, и считаем набором подстрок эти фрагменты и все оставшиеся от такого разбиения фрагменты строки</li>
     *  <li>при сравнении строк осуществляется последовательное сравнение их подстрок до первого несовпадения,</li>
     *  <li>если обе подстроки состоят из цифр - то при сравнении они интерпретируются как целые числа (вначале должно идти меньшее число), в противном случае - как строки,</li>
     *  <li>сортировка должна быть устойчива к исходной сортировке списка - т.е., если строки (в контексте указанных правил сравнения) неразличимы, то сортировка не должна менять их местами.</li>
     * </ul>
     *
     * @param rows список записей таблицы (например, результат sql select), которые нужно отсортировать по указанной колонке
     * @param columnIndex индекс колонки, по которой нужно провести сортировку
     */
    void sort(List<String[]> rows, int columnIndex);
}
```

Реализация класса, в котором наследуется интерфейс. Но сравниваются только строки. Не совсем ясно как реализовать сравнение/упорядочивание подстрок. Ясно, что надо использовать методы `String`, но как это реализовать, чтобы при этом сортировались в требуемом порядке?

```
public void sort(final List<String[]> rows, final int columnIndex) {
    Collections.sort(rows, new Comparator<String[]>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String[] o1, String[] o2) {
            return o1[columnIndex].compareTo(o2[columnIndex]);  
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: А примерчик такой строки есть? Вопрос в том, какой разделитель у этой строки.

Comment: [Вопрос уже поднимался](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/617972/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b9-liststring-rows-int-columnindex-%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d1%83%d1%8e)

Comment: Я спрашивал другое - как реализовать компаратор.

Comment: не совсем понимаю смысл, о каких подстроках идет речь

Comment: покажите на примере, что должно быть в качестве входных данных, а что на выходе